# How to prove the exponent law with rational exponents by Induction

Tags: induction

May I know how to prove that $b^n \times b^m = b^{n+m}$ given that the exponents are now rational numbers instead of pure integers ?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Write
$$
n = \frac pq\\
m = \frac{p'}q
$$
and then use that:
$$
b^n = (b^{\frac 1q})^p
$$